# when I open anaconda prompt it's showing an error of mentioned below.how to resolve this issue?

Tags: python

Invoke-Expression : At line:1 char: 522
...ntel Wireless Common;C:\WINDOWS\System32\OpenSSH;"C:\Mingw\bin;c:\MinG
token 'C:\Mingw\bin' in expression or statement.
C:\Users\admin anaconda3 shell\condabin Conda.psm1:107 char:9
Invoke-Expression -Command SactivateCommand;

- CategoryInfo
  : ParserError: (:) [Invoke-Expression), ParseExcep
  tion
- FullyQualifiedErrorid : Unexpected Token, Microsoft PowerShell.Commands. In
  vokeExpressionCommand

Answer (score 1):

The variables of the path are wrong for the

> "C:\Mingw\bin;c:\MinG token 'C:\Mingw\bin'

have you noticed that there are double quote and single quote there. these signs caused problem. you have to correct these variables in you path.

Answer (score 0):

You can run conda prompt as administrator, It might help you.
Although if this doesn't works you can uninstall Anaconda. Delete all the files located in program files, program files 86 related to Anaconda.

Begin a fresh Installation of Anaconda and check for all the options popped up at the time of installation.
Once installation is completed give it a shot.

1. Go to search and type Anaconda
2. Anaconda will be opened
3. A conda command prompt will be located in the UI.
4. Click on it and check whether it's working.

Hopefully it should work.

If this doesn't works there are some users who have got this problem, You can read it [here](https://github.com/kvos/CoastSat/issues/18).